# Laravel: Cannot get hasOne foreign key data from users table inside a controller

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, charts, eloquent

I want to retrieve data from a foreign key using DB::table query inside my controller but I'm getting an error that says: Property [assigned_to] does not exist on this collection instance. I already made a one to many and inverse relationship between users and the tables.

```
$accesses = DB::table('accesses')
                ->select(array('id', 'fullname','emp_id','shift','state','resolved_at', 'closed_at','assigned_to'))
                ->where('state','=','Assigned');

$all = DB::table('reports')
                ->select(array('id', 'fullname','emp_id','shift','state','resolved_at', 'closed_at','assigned_to'))
                ->union($accesses)
                ->where('state', '=', 'Assigned')
                ->get();

$open_tickets = Charts::database($all, 'bar', 'highcharts')
                ->title("Open Tickets (Assigned)")
                ->elementLabel("Total Assigned Tickets")
                ->dimensions(1000, 500)
                ->responsive(false)
                ->groupBy('assigned_to')
                ->labels($all->assigned_to->name);


//users migration
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('emp_id');
        $table->string('shift');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('contact')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('role')->default('admin');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });


  //reports migration
Schema::create('reports', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->nullable();
        $table->string('fullname');
        $table->string('emp_id');
        $table->string('shift');
        $table->longText('report');
        $table->string('status')->default('Pending'); //Pending, Approved
        $table->string('state')->default('Open'); //Open, Assigned, Resolved, Closed
        $table->date('resolved_at')->nullable();
        $table->date('closed_at')->nullable();
        $table->integer('assigned_to')->nullable();
        $table->longText('action')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });



  //accesses migration|
Schema::create('accesses', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->nullable();
        $table->string('fullname');
        $table->string('emp_id');
        $table->string('shift');
        $table->string('request');
        $table->longText('note')->nullable();
        $table->string('status')->default('Pending'); //Pending, Approved
        $table->string('state')->default('Open'); //Open, Assigned, Resolved, Closed
        $table->date('resolved_at')->nullable();
        $table->date('closed_at')->nullable();
        $table->integer('assigned_to')->nullable();
        $table->longText('action')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

[This is my desired results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXbZc.png)

[this is migrations table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LobD.png)

Comment: can you show us your migrations/structure of the tables?

Comment: check my migrations table below the desired results

Comment: i meant the actual migrations in the code, so i know what your tables look like

Comment: assigned_to is nullable. I know you check for state = assigned. But maybe there is an anomalous entry in your database?